# Accessing my Dockerized website by its hostname

Tags: apache, docker, hostname

On my localhost I have a Docker container serving a PHP website which I can see just fine in my browser `http://localhost/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com/` but I would prefer to access it this way `dev.learnintouch.com/` if that is possible.

I tried running my container with `docker run -d --name learnintouch -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --add-host "dev.learnintouch.com":127.0.0.1 -v /home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch:/usr/bin/apache/htdocs/learnintouch stephaneeybert/learnintouch` but that was not enough.

The container Apache server uses the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev.learnintouch.com
  ServerAlias dev.learnintouch.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/bin/apache/htdocs/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com
  CustomLog logs/learnintouch-access_log combined
  <Directory "/usr/bin/apache/htdocs/learnintouch/www/learnintouch.com">
    Include /usr/bin/apache/htdocs/learnintouch/engine/setup/url_rewrite.conf
  </Directory>
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</VirtualHost>
```

My host's `/etc/hosts` contains:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   stephane-ThinkPad-X301

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I run a Docker with the version:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

The Docker info:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 3
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 150
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /home/stephane/programs/install/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 118
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: overlay bridge null host
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-36-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.693 GiB
Name: stephane-ThinkPad-X301
ID: YMZD:RANJ:QIQ5:3KX3:GNQ6:UIGW:6NG3:YYPU:IABK:XVPI:KPUV:NPSC
Docker Root Dir: /home/stephane/programs/install/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: stephaneeybert
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: include the output of `docker info` and `docker version` to help us out.

Comment: What does `dev.learnintouch.com` resolve to?

Comment: @Matt Sorry for the typo. The `dev.learnintouch.com` is the value passed with the `--add-host "dev.learnintouch.com":127.0.0.1` option. I fixed it in the code example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional hosts you pass in with `--add-host` option will modify your container's /etc/host, not the file on your host itself. For testing, you need to modify the /etc/host on the host running your browser. And for production, you'd need to update DNS to point to the docker host (or a load balancer that includes the docker host as its target).

Comment: Yes I knew that the `--add-host` option is adding to the container's `/etc/hosts` file. I didn't know which `/etc/hosts` file, between the container's and the host's, to add to. So I removed the `--add-host` option then, and only added an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file of my host. And now requesting dev.learnintouch.com gets me the web page all right.